# Aromatic substitution

Tags: acid-base, aromatic-compounds

Respective aromatic substitution: Why isn't the $\pi$ bond attacked by the catalyst $\ce{FeBr3}$?

$\ce{Fe}$ must have a strong partial positive charge and acts as an electron acceptor to form a $\ce{Fe-Br}$ complex, but why can't it accept the electrons from the $\pi$ bond?